# How can I load optional parameter dependent content into a single angular state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm building a front-end that loads a list of content. Think reddit or stackoverflow. Like those sites I want to load different content based on different parameters. For example if a users clicks a meta-tag link on an item, that user will get a list of content sharing that meta-tag. Or if a user searches a keyword they will get content based on that search. I already have separate API calls for getting json based on a tag, a search keyword, and a default route if the user is just seeing what's out there. I also have a mostly working way of handling this in angular but it has an issue and I assume there is a better way to handle this. Now for the code I have. What I'm sharing is setup to work with either the default behavior or a meta-tag link. Search should be easy to extrapolate from this but I haven't bothered yet.

Here I have separate routes for the default load and loading content from a meta-tag. You'll notice both routes share a controller and a template. Also you'll notice the child state 'items.detail'. One issue with my current setup is that I need this child state to work no matter what parameter determined what data was loaded. It loads a modal with more detail on the content. Currently if I loaded the data from a meta-tag it obviously can't resolve items.detail from the 'tags' state.

```
.state('items', {
    url: '/items',
    templateUrl: 'views/items.html',
    controller: 'mainCtrl',
    authenticate: false
}).state('items.detail', {
        url: '/{id}',
        templateUrl: 'views/item-detail.html',
        controller: 'itemDetailCtrl',
        authenticate: false
    })

.state('tags', {
    url: '/items/tag/{tag}',
    templateUrl: 'views/items.html',
    controller: 'mainCtrl',
    authenticate: false
})
```

Here is the controller that handles requesting content after checking if there's a meta tag to use or not and then setting that content to a scope object.

```
module.exports = function ($scope, API, $stateParams) {

    // load data for items
    if ($stateParams.tag) {

        var tag = $stateParams.tag;

        API.getItemsByTag(tag)
            .then(function (res) {
                $scope.items = res.data;
            });

    } else {

        API.getItems()
            .then(function (res) {
                $scope.items = res.data;
            });
    }


};
```

Here is what my api call abstractions look like

```
module.exports = function (Env, $http) {

    // enviroment dependent base url
    var base = Env.baseUrl;

    return {

        getItems : function (count) {
            return $http.get(base + 'items');
        },

        getItemsByTag : function (tag) {
            return $http.get(base + 'items/tags/' + tag);
        },
    };

};
```

What might be a better approach for changing how my main 'items' state calls data based on a tag link or search? Can I pass a variety of optional parameters to a single state?

Side note: You'll notice syntax with 'module.exports' instead of the default app.whatever. I'm using browserify to bundle so that's why it's like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way how we can extend this `use-case` could be observed here in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YfUnxxoDTxiWk1OrH40W?p=preview).
The snippet of the `ui-sref` definition:

```
  <a ui-sref="items({tag:'myTagOne'})">tag: myTagOne</a>
  <a ui-sref="items({tag:'myTagTwo'})">tag: myTagTwo</a> 
  <a ui-sref="items({tag:'myTagTwo', info: 'evenInfo'})">
                                       tag: myTagThree and info: evenInfo</a>

  tag already exists, was set on items/parent state
  <a ui-sref="items.detail({id: 1})">detail: 1 </a>
  <a ui-sref="items.detail({id: 2})">detail: 2 </a>

  tag could be also passed into detail
  <a ui-sref="items.detail({id: 1, tag: null})">detail: 1, tag null </a>
  <a ui-sref="items.detail({id: 2, tag: 'tg'})">detail: 2, tag 'tg' </a>
```

And here is small `state` defintion overview. *(more details [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YfUnxxoDTxiWk1OrH40W?p=preview))*

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('items', {
      url: '/items?tag&info',
      template:...
      controller: ...
    })
    .state('items.detail', {
      url: '/{id:[0-9]{1,8}}',
      template: ...
      controller: ...
    });
```

The Parent *state* could define some `query params` as documented [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters). These are either already set when child state is selected, or could be passed as well:

```
ui-sref="items.detail({id: 2, tag: 'tg', info : '...'})"
```

Comment: Thanks. An example of the ui-sref with query params helped out. I have my main 'items' state accepting 'tag' and 'search' parameters now.

Comment: Great if that helped. The `ui-router` is really great tool. And as your own answer proves, it has very large scalabilty for routing...

Answer (score 1):

Alright I think I've found the correct solution. I ended up using query parameters which I didn't know ui-router was capable of using. My controller didn't actually need to change at all. I still have the if statements checking it query parameters are available and making different api calls if they are. Here are what my routes currently look like. You'll notice the query parameters need to be declared explicitly in the state url. I haven't tested this but I believe you can separate multiple query params with ampersands and they should all be optional.

```
.state('items', {
    url: '/items?tag',
    templateUrl: 'views/items.html',
    controller: 'mainCtrl',
    authenticate: false
}).state('items.detail', {
        url: '/{id}',
        templateUrl: 'views/item-detail.html',
        controller: 'itemDetailCtrl',
        authenticate: false
    })
```

One question that still remains for me is if I can declare query params in my ui-sref. I haven't be able to get that to work yet but my current setup is working with an href. Like so.

```
<a href="#/items?tag={{tag}}" class="meta-tag" ng-repeat="tag in item.tags">{{ tag }}</a>
```

I don't know if there are issues using hrefs with ui-router but I'll be researching that.

Comment: I believe you could use `ui-sref` to provide the `tag` parameter.

Example: `<a ui-sref="items({tag: tag})" class="meta-tag" ng-repeat="tag in item.tags">{{ tag }}</a>`